# Jquery disable link for 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink, onclick

I have this code:

```
   $('#page-refresh').click( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/page1.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#pagelist').html(data);
            }
        });
         return false;
   });
```

In this code is it possible that on the ajax success function it disables the #page-refresh click for 5 seconds then re-enable it? Basically if a person clicks the button and this action happens I dont want them to click and run this action again for another 5 seconds. I looked at delay() to unbind the click for this then bind it again but once it unbinded it never allowed me to click the button anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If "#page-refresh" is really a button (a `button` or `input type="button"` element), you can use its [`disabled`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fe-disabled) property and then set a timeout to restore it:

```
$('#page-refresh').click( function() {
    var refreshButton = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/page1.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#pagelist').html(data);
            refreshButton.disabled = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                refreshButton.disabled = false;
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

If it's not *really* a button, you can simulate the `disabled` property. I'll do it with a class here so you can show the disabled state for the user via CSS:

```
$('#page-refresh').click( function() {
    var $refreshButton = $(this);
    if (!$refreshButton.hasClass('disabled')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/page1.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#pagelist').html(data);
                $refreshButton.addClass('disabled');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $refreshButton.removeClass('disabled');
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Note that in the first case, I'm keeping a reference to the DOM element (`var refreshButton = this;`), but in the second case I'm keeping a reference to a jQuery wrapper around it (`var $refreshButton = $(this);`). That's just because jQuery makes it easy to test/add/remove class names. In both cases, that reference is released once the closures in your event handler are released (in the above, that's five seconds after the ajax call completes).

---

You said specifically you wanted to disable it *after* the ajax call is complete, but as Marcus points out below, you probably want to disable it when *starting* the ajax call. Just move the disabling bit up a bit, and add an `error` handler for the case where `success` doesn't get called (`error` handlers are usually a good idea in any case):

Real button:

```
$('#page-refresh').click( function() {
    var refreshButton = this;
    refreshButton.disabled = true;             // <== Moved
    $.ajax({
        url: "/page1.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#pagelist').html(data);
            setTimeout(function() {
                refreshButton.disabled = false;
            }, 5000);
        },
        error: function() {                    // <== Added
            refreshButton.disabled = false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Simulated via 'disabled' class:

```
$('#page-refresh').click( function() {
    var $refreshButton = $(this);
    if (!$refreshButton.hasClass('disabled')) {
        $refreshButton.addClass('disabled');   // <== Moved
        $.ajax({
            url: "/page1.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#pagelist').html(data);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $refreshButton.removeClass('disabled');
                }, 5000);
            },
            error: function() {                // <== Added
                $refreshButton.removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Maybe a good idea would be to disable the button before the AJAX call goes out (to avoid spamming the AJAX call) and then if the success call comes back use `clearTimeout` to get rid of an existing 5 second time-out and create a new one from that point to re-enable the button.

---

In addition I would probably also have an `error: function () {}` which cleared the time-out and re-enabled the button if that approach was used, to avoid the button remaining disabled for ever in the event of a failed AJAX call.

Comment: @Marcus: Agreed. The question was specific about when they wanted to do it, but I'll add a  note.

Comment: @TJ Yup, just adding my two pennys worth.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
$('#page-refresh').click( function() {
    var btn = $(this);

    // disable button
    btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $.ajax({
         url: "/page1.php",
         cache: false,
         dataType: "html",
         success: function(data) {
             $('#pagelist').html(data);

             // set timer to re-enable button after 5 seconds (or 5000 milliseconds)
             window.setTimeout(function(){
                 btn.removeAttr('disabled');
             }, 5000);
         }
     });
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution to disable a button for 5 seconds:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $(".btn").click(function()
   {            
       var lMilisNow= (new Date()).getTime();
       this.disabled=true; 
       this.setAttribute("data-one-click", lMilisNow); 
        setTimeout("oneClickTimeout()",5100);
    }); 
}

function oneClickTimeout()
{
    $(".btn[data-one-click]").each(function()
    { 
         var lMilisNow= (new Date()).getTime();
         var lMilisAtt= this.getAttribute("data-one-click");
         lMilisAtt= lMilisAtt==null? 0: lMilisAtt;
         if (lMilisNow-lMilisAtt >= 5000 )
         {
             this.disabled=false; 
             this.removeAttribute("data-one-click"); 
         }
     });
}
```